# Post interior margin in twenty eleven theme

Tags: customization, css, theme-twenty-eleven, custom-background

I'm trying to customize the aspect of a single format post, in my case is "Link".
I've added a different color background so they look different, editing the CSS as this:

```
.format-link .entry-content {
    padding: 0;
    font-style: italic;
    background: #d7b5b5; //sfondo rosa
}
```

So they look like this:
http://www.adessomilano.it/wordpress/category/ar/

I'm trying to add a margin between the color and the text in the way there's some free space (but with color background) on left and right side before the text.

I've tried adding Margin and Padding values in the CSS but nothing happens, I think because the padding and the margin space take the white color instead of the pink...

Can someone explain me?

thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, first, it's a pure CSS question.

Second, `padding` is what you want to use.

Just change `padding: 0;` to whatever you like.

I just used FireBug to hack a padding of 1em into your code, and it worked like a charm.

**// Edit**

However, it is not just `.entry-content` but also **`.entry-summary`** that you want to affect.

```
.format-link .entry-content,
.format-link .entry-summary {
    padding: 1em; // for example
    font-style: italic;
    background: #d7b5b5; //sfondo rosa
}
```

**// Edit** - again

It seems, you have to work on your `style.css`.

For [singular posts](http://www.adessomilano.it/wordpress/2013/04/04/resoconto-riunione-adessomilano/), you already defined a different padding:

```
.singular .format-link .entry-content {
    padding: 1.625em 0 0;
}
```

You either have to adapt that as well, or just delete it.

Comment: NO, it works for the excerpt, but not for the article...

Comment: http://www.adessomilano.it/wordpress/category/ar/ it works, but if you click on the title, you can see the padding doesn't affect the article...

Comment: I've tried with the "quote" format and it works perfectly, with both excerpt and full content article. But not with Link format.

Comment: SOLVED! in another part of the CSS there's "article.format-link" with different padding value, this was affecting just the article and not the excerpt. THANK YOU ANYWAY